# Visual Studio ctrl-H sometimes doesn't automatically select 'selection'

Tags: c++, asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio

When I select text then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, the popup dialog doesn't always show "Selection".  Sometimes it gets 'stuck' with "Current Document".

I'm seen this bug for every VS version of Professional and now Community over almost 10 years now...

I select some text, in Visual-C++, then click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
The upper-right replace dialog pops up with "Selection".   This is expected.
Smack <kbd>Esc</kbd> to hide it.
Now, place cursor at empty line.
Click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
Dialog again pops up with "Current Document".  This is expected.
<kbd>Esc</kbd>
Select the same text as in step 1.
Dialog again pops up, BUT with "Current Document" instead of "Selection."
and I have to manually use dialog's pull-down to set for "Selection."

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

I want it to always set "Selection" if I select text then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.

Comment: There are severe design bugs all over the place. My main gripe is that the support for custom keywords for the highlighting, disappeared around 2010 or somewhere. But also the support for `TODO:` in C++ has disappeared, and much else: I think they simply don't have good folks anymore to maintain the animal.

Answer (score 0):

You should select two or more lines to **always** get the Selection option by default on Find and Replace window, this is necessary if you previously opened the Find and Replace window with the Current Document option.